# Extract log file

Tags: unix, scripting, shell

xxxxxxxxmessageyyyyyyymessagexxxxxxxxxx

```
xxxxxxxxmessagezzzzzzzmessagexxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxmessageaaaaaaamessagexxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxmessageyyyyyyymessagexxxxxxxxxx
```

The above is my log file I need to extract the phrase which is inside the message tag and  I need to save the distinct messages in a file in the above example I need to save zzzzzzz and aaaaaaa to a file.

What are the unix commands I need to use.

Comment: Which program produces such a log file? :-S

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. By "the message tag" I suppose you mean 8 x's at the beginning of the line and 10 x's at the end. By "distinct" do you mean that a message should be recorded only once? And are you omitting the yyyyyyy's because they're duplicated, or because they're in the first and last lines?

Comment: ommitting ys because they are duplicated

Comment: that is <message>yyyyyyy</message>

Comment: when i try to print that then entire message tag is disappearing....... thats why i removed grater than and less than symbols there

Comment: And do you have to preserve the order of the messages? That is, is "aaaa zzzz" as good as "zzzz aaaa"?

Comment: @k38: That's because you cannot input tags in the 'normal' mode; just select your text and indent it by clicking the `code` button and tags will be preserved. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
BEGIN
{
  s=0
}

s==0 && /yyyyy/
{
  s=1
  next
}

s==1 && /yyyyy/
{
  exit
}

{
  print
}
```

Run with `awk -f script.awk < infile > outfile`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a dozen ways to accomplish this.  The one I tested:

```
(sed 's/xx//g' | sed 's/message//g')<tstlog >processed.log
```

yielded

```
yyyyyyy

zzzzzzz

aaaaaaa

yyyyyyy
```

Also, if you want to omit the blank lines, you could add something like:

```
(sed 's/xx//g' | sed 's/message//g' | grep -v ^$) < tstlog >processed.log
```